# How to get last inserted non incremental id using eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two models `Customer` and `Address`. My `Customer` has non incremental primary key and is of type `string` which is `customer_id`. The relationship between these two models is of one to many, that means for single `customer` many `addresses` for example: invoice address, delivery address, current address, etc. My `Customer` model is as shown below:

**Customer.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Address','customer_id');
    }
}
```

And my Address model is as shown below:

**Address.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = false;
    // protected $table = "addresses";

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

And following shows the migration for my customers table

**migration for customers table**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('customer_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->date('dob');
            $table->type('country_code');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
    }
}
```

The other thing to note is that my `customer_id` is incremental in sense that I have created separate table namely `customer_sequence` which is auto incremental and before inserting record I append it with two character code using trigger and then place it into my `customers` table.
My customer_sequence migration is as shown below

**customer_sequence Migration**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSequenceCustomers extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sequence_customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('sequence_customers');
    }
}
```

And the trigger that I have used for inserting incrementing string id is as follows:

**Migration for customer_id trigger**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTriggerCustomers extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::unprepared("
        CREATE TRIGGER tg_customer_insert
            BEFORE INSERT ON customers
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO sequence_customers(id) VALUES (NULL);
                IF NEW.type ='Private' THEN
                    SET NEW.customer_id = CONCAT(NEW.country_code, LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, '0'));
                ELSEIF NEW.type='Business' THEN
                    SET NEW.customer_id = CONCAT(NEW.country_code, LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, '0'));
                ELSEIF NEW.type='Reseller' THEN
                    SET NEW.customer_id = LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, '0');
                ELSEIF NEW.type='Distributor' THEN
                    SET NEW.customer_id = LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, '0');
                ELSEIF NEW.type='Other' THEN
                    SET NEW.customer_id = LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, '0');
                END IF;
                IF NEW.credit_amount > NEW.credit_limit THEN
                   SET NEW.credit_limit_exceeded=TRUE;
                ELSE
                    SET NEW.credit_limit_exceeded=FALSE;
                END IF;
            END
        ");
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::unprepared('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tg_customer_insert');
    }
}
```

Now when I save the data of customer and try to get `id` from customer model it returns me `null`. My controller is as shown below:

**CustomerController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $customer = new Customer;
    $invoiceAddress = new Address;
    $deliveryAddress = new Address;

    $customer->name = $request->name;
    $customer->type = $request->type;
    $customer->dob = $request->dob;
    $customer->country_code=$request->country_code;
    $customer->save();

    $deliveryAddress->street_name_no = $request->street_name_no;
    $deliveryAddress->city = $request->city;
    $deliveryAddress->country = $request->country;

    //This throws error customer_id cannot be null integrity constraint
    $deliveryAddress->customer_id = $customer->customer_id;
    $deliveryAddress->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are assigning request values to your customer variable.

```
$customer=new Customer;

$customer=$request->name;
$customer=$request->type;
$customer=$request->dob;
$customer->save();
```

When you are calling `save()`, you are actually calling `save()` on a string. 
Fix it by specifying the fillable properties on your `Customer` model. This is just an example.

```
$customer = new Customer();

$customer->name = $request->name;
$customer->type = $request->type;
$customer->dob  = $request->dob;
$customer->save();
```

After that, `$customer->customer_id` should not be null.

Edit: Failed to notice the following line:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

which means at the time of creating your `Customer` you would also have to supply the `customer_id`, since it is no longer auto-incrementing.

I also took a deeper look at the API. It seems Laravel won't be aware of the attribute set by the trigger at that stage. You can try to `refresh()` the model which will pull in fresh attributes from the DB and assuming your triggers are working fine, you should be getting back a `customer_id`.

So essentially, just add this line before adding the Delivery Address.

```
$customer->refresh();
```

I also noticed you don't have any logic to redirect the user back on successful save.
I suspect this is why it is throwing the 404 since the same route isn't defined for a `GET` request.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $customer        = new Customer;
    $invoiceAddress  = new Address;
    $deliveryAddress = new Address;

    $customer->name = $request->name;
    $customer->type = $request->type;
    $customer->dob  = $request->dob;
    $customer->country_code = $request->country_code;

    $customer->save();

    $customer->refresh(); 

    $deliveryAddress->street_name_no = $request->street_name_no;
    $deliveryAddress->city = $request->city;
    $deliveryAddress->country = $request->country;


    $deliveryAddress->customer_id = $customer->customer_id;
    $deliveryAddress->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'Success message here');
}
```

Edited again:

It seems from the doc, the `refresh()` method is as follows:

```
/**
 * Reload the current model instance with fresh attributes from the database.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function refresh()
{
    if (! $this->exists) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->setRawAttributes(
        static::newQueryWithoutScopes()->findOrFail($this->getKey())->attributes
    );

    $this->load(collect($this->relations)->except('pivot')->keys()->toArray());

    $this->syncOriginal();

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see from the following line:

```
static::newQueryWithoutScopes()->findOrFail($this->getKey())->attributes
```

It will try to find or fail (404) while refreshing the model. I suspect in this case, that it is not able to get the appropriate key and that is why it is failing. I think in this particular case, you will have to get the `customer_id` from the `sequence_customers` table.

Maybe you could get away by doing something like the following:

```
// Assuming SequenceCustomer is the model name
$latest = \App\SequenceCustomer::latest()->first(); 

// and then you would be able to access the latest customer_id by doing the following

$customer_id = $latest->customer_id;
```

This is obviously not a scalable solution, but I am not very sure how else to solve this particular issue :)

Comment: sorry that was the typo, I have updated it now kindly take a look at it.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I am using a sequence from other table that is named 'customer sequence' in which there is autoincrementing id which I am using in trigger and then appending code character for ex SA001 is used as primary key in my customer table.

Comment: Edited my answer again.

Comment: This does'nt solve my problem, now I get error saying page not found.

Comment: I have edited my question and have shown migration for customer_sequence and the trigger.

Comment: The 404 could be unrelated. Was the record saved correctly?

Comment: yes, customer record was inserted but after I did refresh before inserting address data it gave me that error

Comment: Your question was about the record not being inserted which is now fixed. However, I have also edited my answer to include a possible reason as to why you are getting the `404`.

Comment: Still same problem cant redirect to same page, 404 page not found error again.I can save customer but cant address.

Comment: Edited answer again :)

Comment: That did the trick but won't work if there is no column for the timestamp

Comment: You can sort it by the `DESC` on the `customer_id` field and get the latest one.

Comment: Yes that could be one of the solutions too thanks for the help :)